# Fast permutation of bits in C#

Tags: c#, algorithm, bit-manipulation

I'm implementing [Charikar's fast search on a locality sensitive hash](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.110.1930&rep=rep1&type=pdf) and I'm looking for a fast method of permuting bits (the kind of thing that can be done in one operation in MMIX) in C#.

The requirements are:

- Always less than 64 bits, so representation can be a long integer
- Randomly generate a permutation (this can be slow as it's only done once). I'll probably use a Knuth shuffle.
- Use the generated permutation many times, so this needs to be fast

I know Knuth goes into this in detail but I was wondering if there was any .NET/C# specific solution.

EDIT: I'm using .NET version 3.5.

Comment: What about bit permutation in C# do you think is slow?

Comment: @JaredPar: I'm not aware of any bit permutation operators in C# - can you enlighten me? I doubt the standard operations are slow. The problem is for a given permutation, find a series of operations which will compute the permutation as quickly as possible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since C# doesn't provide any bit-manipulation instructions that Knuth didn't have in C, no, there's no .NET/C#-specific solution.

At the same time, .NET does offer dynamic compilation which will help you repeatedly perform the shuffle efficiently.

What version of .NET?  The easiest approach will probably be to use Knuth's algorithm and encode the resulting operations in an `Expression<Func<ulong, ulong>>`, then compile the result as a `Func<long, long>` delegate.

Comment: Thanks, this seems like a sensible solution.